# Displaying an error message as "Directory access is forbidden"

Tags: apache, xampp, filezilla

I had download public_html folder of my website through FileZilla and saved under a newfolder(C:\xampp\htdocs\newfolder) in my local machine. I copied all the public_html contents to my newfolder. When I tried to open the index file under(file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/newfolder/application/index.html), it's displaying an error message as "Directory access is forbidden." I run xampp control panel to start my apache server on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing your global directory settings in **httpd.conf** from

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

To

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

? Or if that doesn't work then changing the

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

To

```
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have tried both the solutions, provided by you. Still, I couldn't find any result. The page remains the same. Alternatively, I  get the following error message: A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\seeyon\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124, when I tried to open through localhost/newfolder